# why moore circuit requires an extra state compared to mealy

Tags: verilog

I have been coding fsm in verilog.why a moore fsm requires an extra state compared to a mealy fsm.Any one can explain me ?. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Mealy FSMs tend to have more states, because in a Moore FSM the number of possible combinations of outputs is equal to the number of states, whereas with a Mealy FSM, the number of possible combinations of outputs is equal to the number of states squared.

Consider an FSM with 1 input and 2 outputs. With a Moore FSM, for all combinations of outputs to be driven, you need 4 states, eg:

```
STATE  OUTPUTS
  A      00
  B      01
  C      10
  D      11
```

With a Mealy FSM, it is possible to drive all 4 combinations of outputs from a FSM with only 2 states, eg:

```
STATE  INPUT  OUTPUTS
  A      0      00
  A      1      10
  B      0      01
  B      1      11
```

So, assuming the FSM's specification is met, the Mealy machine needs 2 states, while the Moore machine needs 4.